# How can I bind my Azure Functions return value to a output?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When using Azure Functions is it possible to bind my outputs to the return value of my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you set your binding name to `$return` then whatever your function returns will be sent to your output binding.  This will avoid you having to specify an `out <T> boundParam` parameter to your function.

### Example:

#### Binding

Using a manual trigger

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "$return",
      "path": "testoutput/{rand-guid}.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "manualTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

#### Code (synchronous)

```
using System;

public static string Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
    await Task.Delay(1);

    return input;
}
```

#### Code (async)

```
using System;

public static async Task<string> Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
    await Task.Delay(1);

    return input;
}
```